# Android WebView onCreate is called each time when app moves to foreground

Tags: android, web-applications, android-activity, webview, foreground

I am creating a simple native android application which has a webview in it. The home screen itself is the webview, thus my android application has only a singe activity which is nothing but the WebviewActivity.
I observe that when ever I put my app in background and then move to fore ground, each time the oncreate is getting executed and always the loadURL is getting called, which basically reloads the whole app.

Is there any way to stop this beahviour ? I want the user to see the application immediately on coming to fore ground, with no reload happening.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println(">>>> Starting Intent Filter name = " + getIntent());

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com//");


}
```

Please help.

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: see android lifecycle [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Activity-onCreate-and-Callback-Methods.html)

Comment: I knew the android life cycle, the activity is not getting destroyed. still while coming to foreground, the oncreate is getting called. Above is my code.

Comment: check your developer settings-> `limit background process`.. select  `standard limit`

Comment: Android decides when to destroy the activity.

Comment: Developer settings is set to standard limit only..
Android won't destroy my activity whenever I go background. Here the issue is everytime the onCreate is getting called when the app comes foreground

Comment: I see the onDestroy is getting called for the activity whenever it goes to background

Comment: can you post your `onPause()` method code?

Comment: I have not written anything in onPause, only super.onPause(). Both onPause and onDestroy are getting called when the app moved to background..Is that because my activity only has <Webview > and no other layouts ?